# Python imports - why main package name is required?

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to know why I need to include the main directory name in the `import` statements for creating my project's directory structure.

## My project's structure

```
.
├── main.py
├── myModel
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── loader
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── dataset_loader.py
│   └── models
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── static_model.py
│       └── task_model.py
└── tree.txt
```

#### main.py

```
from myModel import loader
from myModel import models

loader.fun ()
loader.dataset_loader.fun ()
```

#### myModel/__init__.py

```
import myModel.models
import myModel.loader
```

#### myModel/loader/__init__.py

```
from myModel.loader.dataset_loader import *
```

#### myModel/models/__init__.py

```
from myModel.models.static_model import StaticModel
```

My first question is why I need to put `myModel` even in subfolders of the `myModel` directory. I tried to remove it, but `import` didn't work so I think it needs to be there.

Secondly, why I can call `fun` directly from `loader` and not using the full qualified path?

I read [something on the web](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html). But I still have trouble understanding why this happens.

Comment: Have you read about [relative imports](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#absolute-vs-relative-import)?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelButscher. The thing was that they are not adviced (see: `In general, absolute imports are preferred over relative imports. They avoid the confusion between explicit vs. implicit relative imports.`). What probably I am asking is that If the way I posted is also the right way to do it in Python.

Comment: @Guido. They are perfectly fine within a self contained package. Python is, above all, a pragmatic language.

Comment: As the implicit relative imports are only supported by the slowly vanishing Python 2.x they are a minor issue today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute imports, like `import x.y.z` or `from x.y import z` require `x` to be in your path. In your specific case, `myModel` is on the path because of your working directory. The sub-packages are not on the path, and can therefore only be accessed by reiterating the root package.

A more intuitive approach might be to use relative paths. This is possible because all your files live in proper packages with `__init__` files. Keep in mind that relative paths imply that you have modules that are designed to live in your package structure and not on their own. Otherwise, you may end up causing errors when you try to run some of the modules as standalone scripts.

Change `myModel/__init__.py` to:

```
from . import models
from . import loader
```

The `.` makes the import relative. Notice that I did not suggest changing `main.py`, since it lives outside your packages. Adding more dots lets you go up more levels in the file hierarchy.

Change `myModel/loader/__init__.py` to

```
from .dataset_loader import *
```

and `myModel/models/__init__.py` to

```
from .static_model import StaticModel
```

An `import` statement binds a name in your local namespace (usually the module you are executing it in). The name that is bound depends on which form of `import` you used:

1. `import x` binds the module described in `x.py` or `x/__init__.py` to the name `x`
2. `import x.y` binds the module described in `x.py` or `x/__init__.py` to the name `x`, and insures that `x` has an attribute `y`, either as an attribute defined in `x.py`/`__init__.py`, or as a sub-module in `x/y.py`.
3. `from x import y` binds the attribute or sub-module `y` from `x.py`/`x/__init__.py` or `x/y.py` to the name `y`. This option loads, but does not give you access to `x`.

When you run `from myModel import loader`, you get a module object `loader` that has a callable attribute `fun`.

Comment: With this method, if I change the structure and let's say I add a folder between `myModel` and `loader` I do not need to change the relative import statements, correct?

Comment: @Guido. Yes, but you'd need to do that for absolute imports too. Changing structure is changing structure, no matter how you describe it.